# Compare subgroups within each group using multiple comparison correction

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons

I have a similar problem to the `ToothGrowth` dataset

I have the following

```
boxplot(len ~ supp*dose, data=ToothGrowth, notch=TRUE, 
              col=(c("gold","darkgreen")), main="Tooth Growth", 
              xlab="Suppliment and Dose")
View(ToothGrowth)
```

[image: ToothGrowth boxplot]

I would like to compare VC vs. OJ within each dose, while using multiple comparison correction (TukeyHSD).

Is this possible with the `TukeyHSD(aov(...))` function?